# I want to create 'join' and 'list' command

Tags: python, database, command, discord.py

So basically I want to have 2 commands, which is:

1. !join
2. !list

So for the first command, the player will join the list. Once the list is full (10/10 player), players cannot join.
Then, for the second command player will be able to check all players that joined.

Comment: Welcome. Stack Overflow does not provide code writing services. What do you know and have already? What have you tried? Did you read a tutorial about Discord.py?

Comment: i have no information about these, i aksed some helper, but I dont understand. I need like an example and their fuction.

Comment: Noone understand what im asking or what, noone is reponding my question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know, I never implemented a Python bot, so I thought I could try it, just for fun. I started with [a tutorial](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) . Hardest stuff: [registering an app](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and managing all the permissions to [make the bot appear in my channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/discord.html#discord-intro).

25 minutes later I came up with what I understand as your question:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
joined = []

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global joined
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("!join"):
        if len(joined) == 10:
            await message.channel.send("List full")
            return
        if message.author not in joined:
            joined.append(message.author)
        else:
            await message.channel.send("You joined already.")

    if message.content.startswith("!list"):
        usernames = [user.name for user in joined]
        await message.channel.send("\n".join(usernames))

client.run('<your token>')
```